# How to make Idris warn of incomplete cases/matches?

Tags: idris

For example when implementing a `Show` instance for the following type:

```
data Shape = Circle Double
           | Box Vector2D
           | Polygon (List Vector2D)
           | Chain (List Vector2D)
```

...and omitting the `Chain` case, Idris will successfully type check this file.

Similar issues go for implementing other functions.

Adding `%default total` at the beginning of the file doesn't seem to help this, but my impression was that it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this:

```
%default total

data DataType = A | B | C

Show DataType where
  show A = "A"
```

I get

```
$ idris Testme.idr
Type checking ./Testme.idr
Testme.idr:5:1-13:
  |
5 | Show DataType where
  | ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Main.DataType implementation of Prelude.Show.Show is possibly not total due to: Prelude.Show.Main.DataType implementation of Prelude.Show.Show, method show
```

Please note that you will not see this kind of warnings in Atom - they do not seem part of the compiler / editor protocol.

Comment: ah yeah that's the issue: I was expecting that Atom would report that message

Answer (score 0):

There is an option you can call `idris` with:

> --total                  Require functions to be total by default

I'm still not sure if this is the only way, why `%default total` seems to do nothing, and whether it's possible to only get a warning when a function is not total.